# api url to remove member from azure active directory security group

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Need a Graph Api url that can be used to delete member from azure active directory security group.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please demonstrate a good will and explain what have you done so far to solve your issue, what is the expected result and what is the actual result. You may use any familiar internet search engine to first lookup the information you need on your own and try it.

Comment: Please read the following documentation, then edit and rephrase the question.  [Take the Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) & [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) & [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) & [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users).  From [review](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/24103839).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following is an example of the request. Refer to the document [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/group-delete-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).

```
DELETE https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/groups/{id}/members/{id}/$ref
```

And here is my test result:

[image]

Comment: Its working in postman    can you help me out where  to add delete method in my java code.(I am a beginner in java)

Comment: @sqldeveloper You can refer to https://techndeck.com/how-to-send-http-delete-request-using-apache-httpclient-in-java/

Comment: @sqldeveloper Do you have any other concerns regarding this?

Comment: @Tonu Ju Nothing more Thank you